# Apache Cordova - Problema con Developer Team IOS 10

Tags: apache, cordova, phonegap

Actualmente tengo un problema al compilar el proyecto de **Apache Cordova** para la plataforma IOS 10.

Lo que sucede es al ejecutar en la terminal el comando:

`sudo cordova build ios --device`

sale un error solicitando el "Developer Team" o codigo de desarrollador Apple.

Ya he solucionado el problema importando el proyecto a XCODE y cambiando algunas configuraciones, pero me parece muy curioso que no funcione correctamente desde la terminar y me imagino que debe existir un forma correcta de asignar el Id de desarrollador.

He consultado en varios sitios oficiales y he encontrado una solución que se publico en Septiembre por parte del equipo de desarrollo de Apache Cordova, pero no he encontrado la forma correcta de implementarlo. El sitio es el siguiente: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11845

Para solucionar este problema modifique el archivo `build.xcconfig` sin éxito.

El error en cuestión es el siguiente:

> Signing for "holaMundo" requires a development team. Select a
>   development team in the project editor. Code signing is required for
>   product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

Si alguien a solucionado este problema de una forma diferente a importarlo en `XCODE`, se lo agradezco.

Muchas gracias por su atención.

Saludos,

Comment: prueba con la nueva version de cordova-ios (4.3.0)

Comment: Hola, si pruebo con dicha version, no podre generar correctamente el proyecto para IOS 10, muchas gracias

Comment: como que no? esa versión ya soporta el developer team, prueba mejor la 4.3.1 que salió después de mi comentario http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/platforms/ios/index.html#using-buildjson